# Sqoop-Job Command Fails when Try to Connect to SQL Server while Sqoop-Import does not

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to create and execute a `sqoop job` to get data from a SQLSERVER and import it into Hive, but the command fails in the authentication process. However if I execute the exactly same command by using `sqoop import` it does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Please, consider the example:

`$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_USERNAME` and `$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_PASSWD` are 'admin'

`"sqoop job --create $EXTRACTION_NAME -- import --connect '$CONNECTION_CFG_PREFIX_QUERY_STRING$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_IP:$CONNECTION_CFG_SQLSERVER_
PORT;database=$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_NAME' --username $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_USERNAME --password $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_PASSWD --table $CONNECTION_CFG_HIVE_TABLE_
NAME --target-dir $EXTRACTION_TARGET_DIR/$ID --hive-import --hive-database $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_NAME --hive-table $CONNECTION_CFG_HIVE_TABLE_NAME --hive-partition-k
ey $HIVE_TABLE_PARTITION_KEY --hive-partition-value $ID -m $SQOOP_PARALLELISM --check-column $INCREMENTAL_FIELD --incremental lastmodified"`

This above one fails. I get the following output:

`ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'admin'. ClientConnectionId:25424a39-dd01-4439-bfc6-d7ef21c8b1a0`

However, this one below works!

`"sqoop --import --connect '$CONNECTION_CFG_PREFIX_QUERY_STRING$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_IP:$CONNECTION_CFG_SQLSERVER_PORT;database=$CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_NAME' --username $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_USERNAME --password $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_PASSWD --table $CONNECTION_CFG_HIVE_TABLE_NAME --target-dir $EXTRACTION_TARGET_DIR/$ID --hive-import --hive-database $CONNECTION_CFG_DATABASE_NAME --hive-table $CONNECTION_CFG_HIVE_TABLE_NAME --hive-partition-key $HIVE_TABLE_PARTITION_KEY --hive-partition-value $ID -m $SQOOP_PARALLELISM --check-column $INCREMENTAL_FIELD --incremental lastmodified"`

I need to use `sqoop job` since I do not know the value of `last-value` parameter and I would like to sqoop handle it automatically for me.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Any chance your password has an exclamation mark? Also, please remove any special characters like `\n` or other from the end of the file. If everything fails, try to create a new password file and provide it again using `--password`. Make sure it does not contain ***any special character***. Also, make sure you have different ports for different SQL servers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. However, the password is exactly the same as the username. Both were set as 'admin'

Comment: Rather than saying the password you can say there is no special character in it. Coming to the ports, how many different SQL servers are you running? Are they using same ports?

Comment: Only a single SQL server instance